# How to use FPDI SetSourceFile with a URL that redirects?

Tags: php, fpdi

I've got a PDF file on my server, and I want to use it as parameter for this function:

[$fpdi->setSourceFile()](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v1/the-fpdi-class/#index-3-1)

The problem is that the link used as a source redirects to another URL and I don't know the final URL.
It seems that `setSourceFile` needs the real PDF filename.
Is there a way to get the final URL, and then pass it as parameter?

Comment: You mean you don't have the local path for the file, just a normal URL?

Comment: @EnricoDias not exactly: I've got an URL like: https://example.com/12/PDF/ and if I open this url it is redirected to something like  https://example.com/file_12.pdf but I cannot rebuild the file name from the url rewrited. If I run setSourceFile("https://example.com/12/PDF/") it doesn't work, If I run setSourceFile("https://example.com/file_12.pdf") it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your question according to the explanation you gave in the comments. This is not related to a rewrite, it's related to URL redirection.

#### Solution 1: open a stream manually

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/a395a1cc788dfd0c15f9c69dc7e94f3d186836f8/src/FpdiTrait.php#L149) for this specific function and it expects to receive either a filename or a Stream. You could fetch the PDF link manually, process the redirects and pass the final Stream to this function:

```php
$stream = fopen('https://example.com/12/PDF', 'rb', false, stream_context_create());

$fpdi->setSourceFile($stream);
```

You can tweak the headers and other parameters such as cookies in the [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) function if needed. It's likely that the remote server requires a cookie or something before redirect to the final URL.

#### Solution 2: download the file

If you pass a link to this function it will recognize it as a `String` and [try to open it as a file](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/a395a1cc788dfd0c15f9c69dc7e94f3d186836f8/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php#L40). Since you stated that passing a link that doesn't redirect works, your server is allowing the function `fopen()` to open external links. If that's the case, you could simply use ordinary file functions to download the PDF to a local folder temporarily:

```php
// saves the file locally
file_put_contents('localFile.pdf', file_get_contents('https://example.com/12/PDF'));

// do what you need to do with it
$fpdi->setSourceFile('localFile.pdf');

// deletes the file after using it
unlink('localFile.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks your solution 2 works well and is very simple.